# Replacement for the Rubber Rim of a 12V Train Motor

Tags: trains, wheel, replacement-parts

The [12V Train Motor Item No: 7865-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7865-1) needs a [rubber train rim](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=trainrim) for traction. Unfortunately I could not find any new ones and the old rubber of used items dried out.
The rim must be soft and rough, but also thin. The force of the spring for the contact studs is reduced, if the rim is too thick.

How to replace the rim with products available in Germany?

Answer (score 1):

Some bicycle tubes can be used as a replacement. Depending on the model you find there might be a need to file the seam once you cut a ring from the tube.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have the original part at hand and so can't compare its physical characteristics, I suppose duct tape (cut to size) might be used depending on the target thickness, pliability and surface stickiness.

Answer (score 0):

Flat square rubber rings like these are used in many types of plumbing fixtures like mixing valves used in bathtubs and showers.

In the USA these are called square rings, Bradley rings or flat rings.

Suggest that the OP look for this at a plumbing supply vendor in Germany.